# Username turned into hash, avatar changing random

Tags: support, bug, display-names

I've got an issue with my username, only on the *Software Quality Assurance and Testing* website. I believe that is the reason my avatar is not working, eighter.

On every exchange, my username is *randy*. Until recently my username was working fine on the *Software Quality Assurance & Testing* site as well. Today I've visited the site again because I clicked my rep change, and noticed my username was something like a hash value.

My reputation is working fine, I just wonder why this happened and if there is a way I can fix this.

---

SQA&T:
[image]

Stack overflow:
[image]